# How does Spark occupy the memory

Tags: apache-spark

If my server has 50GB memory, Hbase is using 40GB. And when I run Spark I set the memory as `--executor-memory 30G`. So will Spark grab some memory from Hbase since there only 10GB left. 
Another question, if Spark only need 1GB memory, but I gave Spark 10G memory, will Spark occupy 10GB memory.

Comment: Partly Answered your question. For complete solution you need to add some more info about environment and also When you say that **i gave Spark 10G memory** which parameter are you talking about? Please add the same as part of your question and I will elaborate the provided response.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior will be different depending upon the deployment mode. In case you are using local mode, then `--executor-memory` will not change anything as you only have 1 Executor and that's your driver, so you need to increase the memory of your driver.

In case you are using Standalone mode and submitting your job in cluster mode then following would be applicable: -

1. `--executor-memory` is the memory required by per executor. It is the executors Heap Size. By Default 60% of the configured --executor-memory is used to cache RDDs. The remaining 40% of memory is available for any objects created during task execution. this is equivalent to -Xms and -Xmx. so in case you provide more memory then available then your executors will show errros regarding insufficient memory.

Answer (score 0):

When you give Spark executor 30G memory, OS will not give it actual physical memory. But As and when your executor requires actual memory to either cache or processing this will cause your other processes like hbase to go on to swap. If your system's swap is set to zero then you will face OOM Error.

OS Swaps out idle part of the process which could make your process behave very slow.